# Informatica Bad files

Tags: caching, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am using INFORMATICA PWC 10.0.2 .
I have some workflows that crashed recently due to insufficient space for session cache and I have discovered a huge file called Bad files (More than 60 GO)  is it okay if i deleted it or there is a risk ? also the cache is it okay to delete them after every run or  not ?

Thank you .

Answer (score 1):

**Bad files**

`.bad` files contain data that has been rejected by the Target. This may occur due to different reasons, e.g. trying to instert string to integer column. `.bad` file content makes it possible to verify the exact reason for error.

Can it be deleted? Well - this depends on the nature and source of your data.

- If the source is still available for reload: most likely you can simply delete it
- If the source does not have the data anymore this might be the only copy you have

My guess is (especially if this is some dev environment) that implementation does not meet source / target expected data types and simply everything gets dumped to `.bad` file.

**Cache files**

Cache files are deleted automatically after successfull run. The cleanup won't be run if session fails. In 99% of the cases it's safe to remove them. Just keep in mind sorter cache is stored in `$PMTempDir`, not as other cache files that are created in `$PMCacheDir`. See the [docs](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/data-services/10-1/_application-service-guide_data-services_10-1_ditamap/powercenter_integration_service_architecture/output_files_and_caches/cache_files_1.html) for details.

So no need to do the cleanup after every run - only after failures. If every run fails... well, some fixing needs to be done first :)